# Bootstrap: How to make columns equal height / dynamic amount of columns per row depending on device size

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have taken this code basically from the Purity III joomla template:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail"><img alt="Sample image" src="/images/joomlart/corporate/staff-1.jpg" class="img-circle">
<div class="caption">
<h3>Sean Thomas</h3>
<p>Senior Designer</p>
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail"><img alt="Sample image" src="/images/joomlart/corporate/staff-1.jpg" class="img-circle">
<div class="caption">
<h3>Sean Thomas</h3>
<p>Senior Designer</p>
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail"><img alt="Sample image" src="/images/joomlart/corporate/staff-1.jpg" class="img-circle">
<div class="caption">
<h3>Sean Thomas</h3>
<p>Senior Designer</p>
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail"><img alt="Sample image" src="/images/joomlart/corporate/staff-1.jpg" class="img-circle">
<div class="caption">
<h3>Sean Thomas</h3>
<p>Senior Designer</p>
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail"><img alt="Sample image" src="/images/joomlart/corporate/staff-1.jpg" class="img-circle">
<div class="caption">
<h3>Sean Thomas</h3>
<p>Senior Designer</p>
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail"><img alt="Sample image" src="/images/joomlart/corporate/staff-1.jpg" class="img-circle">
<div class="caption">
<h3>Sean Thomas</h3>
<p>Senior Designer</p>
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This works as it should:
Three colums per row on a normal device (http://www.bootply.com/SN4RsM0gtI)
[image]
and two columns on a smaller screen.

The problem stars when one DIV is higher than the others (http://www.bootply.com/lRDhpndazO):
[image]
I could wrap three divs within a "row"-class , then it works on a normal screen, but on smaller device the second row will contain only one column.

Any idea how to go on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Used a flexbox for the container and edited the html a bit. Hope this works for you, please give me your feedback. Thanks!

snippet below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container .thumbnail {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 thumbnail">
    <img alt="Sample image" src="/images/joomlart/corporate/staff-1.jpg" class="img-circle">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Sean Thomas</h3>
      <p>Senior Designer</p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 thumbnail">
    <img alt="Sample image" src="/images/joomlart/corporate/staff-1.jpg" class="img-circle">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Sean Thomas</h3>
      <p>Senior Designer</p>
      <p>content</p>
      <p>content</p>
      <p>content</p>
      <p>content</p>
      <p>content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 thumbnail">
    <img alt="Sample image" src="/images/joomlart/corporate/staff-1.jpg" class="img-circle">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Sean Thomas</h3>
      <p>Senior Designer</p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 thumbnail">
    <img alt="Sample image" src="/images/joomlart/corporate/staff-1.jpg" class="img-circle">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Sean Thomas</h3>
      <p>Senior Designer</p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 thumbnail">
    <img alt="Sample image" src="/images/joomlart/corporate/staff-1.jpg" class="img-circle">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Sean Thomas</h3>
      <p>Senior Designer</p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 thumbnail">
    <img alt="Sample image" src="/images/joomlart/corporate/staff-1.jpg" class="img-circle">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Sean Thomas</h3>
      <p>Senior Designer</p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One JS solution is to get the max height of the thumbnail containers and then set this max height to all thumbnail containers. The following snippet requires jQuery.

```
<script>
var maxHeight = 0;
$('.thumbnail').each(function () {
  var height = $(this).height();
  if (height > maxHeight){
     maxHeight = height;
  }
});
$('.thumbnail').height(maxHeight);
</script>
```

Comment: You use bootstrap, so you need equal height columns with fluid width. You can use flexbox method, but you can try also with tables.